# Facebook Sharing Fails on Non Admin Devices

Tags: java, android

I have and android app in which i want to Post image and message to faceboook. I Have completed all Steps including facebook key from console hash key from program and save to facebook console. So when i run App it is posting image and message successfully only from my device in which same facebook account is used. But When i try from any other device it is not posting data to facebook and it gives me error **"publish permission [publish action] not accepted by user"**. i got stuck at this point. please help me. what should i do. I read some articles and got idea that facebook change its policy and app should send to review. but i have not idea what and how necessary credentials required to facebook. please help me i have to complete my app as soon as possible. i am already getting late. i am searching from 2 weeks but at last decided to post question here. please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: From the error you have it looks like you didn't accept the dialog with publish permission and thus you couldn't publish photo.

Comment: Visit this link https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/issues/187